# How do I target an Effect with a Trigger?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my WPF application, I am writing a custom template for a ComboBox. I want the combobox to attain an elevated-shadow effect when the user mouses over it, so I tried writing this code:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Border x:Name="templateRoot"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            CornerRadius="4" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0" MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border x:Name="Shadow"
                    Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Margin="-3"
                    Background="{DynamicResource L1Brush}">
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect x:Name="ShadowEffect"
                                      BlurRadius="0" ShadowDepth="0" />
                </Border.Effect>
            </Border>
            <!-- rest of the template -->
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <!-- other triggers -->
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="ShadowEffect" Property="DropShadowEffect.BlurRadius" Value="5" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="ShadowEffect" Property="DropShadowEffect.BlurRadius" Value="5" />
        </Trigger>
        <!-- other triggers -->
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

However, at runtime, it throws an error, citing that the name `ShadowEffect` doesn't exist. How do I make this work? And how would I reference `ShadowEffect` from a Storyboard if I wanted to animate this?

I realise that I can just set the entire `Effect` property of the Border, but this approach falls apart if I try to add animation.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually kind of annoying; you can't give a `Setter` a path. Even if anything here had a property named `DropShadowEffect`, you couldn't get to it. You could use animation but that's a lot more verbose and I don't have all night.

What you can do instead is the old `Tag` hack. `Tag` is up for grabs, and it's a dependency property so it'll update bindings when its value changes. `Border.Tag` gets initialized to zero, the setters set it to 5, and the `DropShadowEffect` binds its `BlurRadius` to it.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" x:Key="ComboTemplate">
    <Border x:Name="templateRoot"
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
        CornerRadius="4" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0" MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border 
                x:Name="Shadow"
                Grid.Column="0" 
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Margin="-3"
                Background="{DynamicResource L1Brush}"
                Tag="0"
                >
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect 
                        BlurRadius="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Border}}" 
                        ShadowDepth="0" 
                        />
                </Border.Effect>
            </Border>
            <!-- rest of the template -->
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <!-- other triggers -->
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Shadow" Property="Tag" Value="5" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Shadow" Property="Tag" Value="5" />
        </Trigger>
        <!-- other triggers -->
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: This is a clever solution, thanks! But one more thing - `<Trigger.EnterActions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="ShadowEffect">
                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="BlurRadius" To="5" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </Trigger.EnterActions>` seems to do the trick, but the animation is very choppy. Why?

Comment: @333 you’d need to set From and To on the DoubleAnimation IIRC. That’s the solution I would have preferred but had no time to look up. Now I’m at the bar I was heading out to.